# How can you get input from user in 'Output' section instead of 'Terminal' section in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Can you get input from a user in the `OUTPUT` section instead of the `TERMINAL` section in Visual Studio Code?

I just installed Visual Studio Code and when I try to get input from the user, the cursor in the output terminal doesn't even blink to allow input to be entered.

Unless I go to the `TERMINAL` section I can't enter any input. What is the problem?

I am using `python`.

Comment: there is an extension called Code Runner for VSCode which can help you....

Comment: Related: [Code Runner in VSCode is running in output instead of CMD in the Terminal](/q/63148583)

Answer (score 0):

If you download the extension named "code runner", there will be three options for you to choose to run the code.

[image]

[image]

The result will shows in the OUTPUT if you choose the first **"run code"**. You cannot type anything in it. This is the setting of output. We cannot modify this.

The result will shows in terminal if you choose the seconde **"run python file"**. You can use the terminal like cmd or any other shells.

The third is for debugging, it has nothing to do with this problem.